# Problem with Constructors

Tags: c#, class-library

****Just below is my winform client inst with one parameter constructor within the class.****

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string s1 = textBox1.Text;
        int x1 =  Convert.ToInt32(s1);
        int X= x1;        
       ExternalTest ob =  new ExternalTest(X);                 
       string s2 = Convert.ToString(ob.Y);              
        ob.Y = 0;
       textBox2.Text = s2;
```

**And below this is my class that i added to the project**
The code below is an added class within the assembly.  If i tried to make it a class library and and add addreference  - it will not build.

```
class ExternalTest       
{      
            private int _x;
       //     protected new int x
       //     {
       //        get { return _x; }
       //        set  {_x = value ;}
       //     }
             private int y;
             public  int Y 
            {                 
              get {return y =  Mult(_x); }
              set { }
            }        
                internal   int Mult(int _x)
              {                       
              y = _x + 51;   
               return  y;         
               }    

            public ExternalTest(int X)
           {
               _x =  X;             

           }            

      }
}
```

Comment: This should have been a continuation of your original question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189139/class-library-in-c/3189178#3189178) rather than a new one.

Comment: @clalbert: please take the time to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). You may learn not to post duplicate questions, but rather to keep all information about your question in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Your class is not `public` by default. You must add `public` to the definition of the class when you're using it in an external library, or the WinForms client will not be able to see it.

EG:

```
public class ExternalObj
{
    // ... 
}
```

Based on the fact that you are getting a compile error only when this class is in an external library, and the numerous times I've forgotten to add `public` when I've needed it myself, I'm thinking this is probably the issue.